# Restoring TTY cursor after boot splash

Tags: plymouth

I'm using Plymouth boot splash on Raspbian Lite with great success, using [this guide](https://scribles.net/customizing-boot-up-screen-on-raspberry-pi/). By adding `vt.global_cursor_default=0` in `/boot/cmdline.txt` it hides the blinking cursor during the boot sequence. Great!

However now (of course) I don't have a blinking cursor when using local or SSH TTY. Is there a way to bring back the cursor once the system has completed booting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115009/how-to-change-the-cursor-theme-in-cli). By adding `tput cnorm` (underlined cursor) or `tput cvvis` (block cursor) to my user's login script in `~/.bashrc` TTY works again as normal.